# How can I install Ultrastar Deluxe on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: software-installation, ultrastar-deluxe

I'd like to install Ultrastar Deluxe on Ubuntu 14.10. [Tobias Doerffel's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ubuntu/ultrastardx) only contains Ultrastar Deluxe for Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I install Ultrastar Deluxe on Ubuntu 14.10?